# Error reading from png.class

Tags: android, google-tv

When I attempt to load an image from a URL, using the following code (real image path removed):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL("http://some-path/img.png").getContent());
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error reading from ./org/apache/harmony/awt/www/content/image/png.class
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing the error?

I am using a GoogleTV AVD, if that matters.

Comment: Is the server response code 200?

Comment: Yes. I confirmed the URL's are valid.

Comment: I used a packet sniffer just to make sure, and the image requests are being made, and a 200 response with the image is returned.

Comment: Have you tried making a post request using httpclient, and response from the server with a byte array or something similar? if you recieve the byte array, you can construct a bitmap from that  Just a tought that popped up. If you need a simple example, let me know

Answer (score 4):

I hope this will be sufficient.

If you are using php;

```
echo base64_encode($imgBinary); // You can get the imagebinary by using the fread and fopen methods provided by php
```

on android:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

if(entity != null) {
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(convertStreamToString(is), Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
}
```

This is probably not the most efficient way, but it should do the job.
From there on you can build :)

You can compress the bitmap into a PNG after, and safe it. example:

```
decodedByte.compress(compressformat, quality, stream);//suported compress formats can be used like so: Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG etc
```

convertStreamToString are easily found methods. Just do a quick google search, or write your own.

Answer (score 2):

Try this method: its working for me This returns bitmap

```
bmp=getBitmapFromURL(ur url here);
```

write this method

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {  
        try {

            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            return mybitmap;

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have experienced the scenario like yours i found that the input stream for an image cannot be obtained by simple methods of getting stream try to update the following things in your code and then check results. I'm sure you will get what you want.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getBitmapStream("http://some-path/img.png"));
```

and here is the method which can be declared within class to be called directly in your decode stream method

```
public InputStream getBitmapStream (String url)
{
    HttpGet httpRequest = null;
    InputStream instream=null;
    try {
        URL bitmapUrl=new URL(url);
            httpRequest = new HttpGet(bitmapUrl.toURI());
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute
    (httpRequest);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity
    (entity);
            instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent(); 
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return instream;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be

```
URL url = new URL("some url path");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
BitmapDrawable image = new BitmapDrawable(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```